# @uses and @throws aren't resolving in phpDocumentor2

Tags: php, doctrine, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I'm using [phpDocumentor2](http://www.phpdoc.org/) to compile docs for my code.  DocBlocks containing @throws and @uses aren't quite compiling the way I would expect.

Specifically, the FQSEN is not being rendered in the documentation output.

**For Example**

```
/**
 * Constructs the object and loads data.
 * 
 * This constructor invokes the gatherData and populates the object's instance variables.
 *
 * @uses gatherData() to load in the data associated with this object.
 * @uses load() to populate the data gathered.
 */
```

Generates...

[image: A screenshot of the resulting documentation]

Notice that "gatherData()" and "load()" method names appear nowhere in the output.  Their descriptions do, however.

I'm seeing a similar effect for @throws tags.

Is this expected behavior?  Am I misusing the tags?

Answer (score 2):

If those are methods of some class, you should specify them like

```
@uses SomeClass::gatherData() to load in the data associated with this object.
```

The original phpdocumentor didn't supported namespaces, you might need to switch to the [phpdocumentor2](http://www.phpdoc.org/) version.

Comment: Great point -- should I be suing SomeClass even if the class scope is of the same class as __construct?  I think I tried this with no luck, unfortunately.

I should also update my post, as I am using phpdocumentor2, not phpdocumentor.

Comment: Update: The bad news is that even adding FactoryObject:: the documentation output stays the same.  I also tried removing the namespaces just for kicks and no luck!  *snaps fingers*

Comment: I have a memory of this working, but it really sounds like some bug then.

Comment: Noted -- filed a bug report: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/920 ||  I will likely mark this as answer (will hold off for a bit just in case)  Thanks for letting me know I'm not going crazy, at least.

Comment: There seem to be [some changes around these parts](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/commit/26b791f5693d0d1d8898713616053c3428e1cf53) recently, I've added what i could gather about this to the issue.